# Could a 'Bartertown'- type power source work?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, technology

In the film Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome, the community called Bartertown derives energy from burning methane gas given off of the manure of pigs they keep penned.

Does this actually seem like a feasible power source for even a small town (less than a population of a hundred)? Would other types of livestock be better suited  and how many would be needed (again, for about a hundred people, bare minimum needs for survival rather than comfortable)?

Comment: you can get energy from biogas. It's actually a real thing in real life even tho the gas mostly comes from biological waste of any kind and not only pig manure.

Answer (score 5):

They get power not from the pigs, [but from the pig shit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089530/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu).

> Aunty Entity: We call it Underworld. That's where Bartertown gets its energy.
>
> Max: What, oil? Natural gas?
>
> Aunty Entity: Pigs.
>
> Max: You mean pigs like those?
>
> Aunty Entity: That's right.
>
> Max: Bullshit!
>
> Aunty Entity: No. Pig shit.
>
> Max: What?
>
> The Collector: Pig shit. The lights, the motors, the vehicles, all run by a high-powered gas called methane. And methane cometh from pig shit.

This is important, because it's not like they keep them in special chambers to capture pig farts. If you want to know about that, read [*Methane production of growing and finishing pigs in southern China*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377840111001507), though that's more focused on measuring methane production for greenhouse gas calculations than capturing it.

If you want to make methane from pig shit, it turns out there's a paper for that! [*Generating Methane Gas From Manure*, Department of Agricultural Engineering, University of Missouri](http://extension.missouri.edu/p/G1881) by Charles D. Fulhage, Dennis Sievers and James R. Fischer.

They reckon a 150 pound pig will produce 70 usable BTUs per hour. That's not a lot. A refrigerator needs about 3000 BTUs per hour. So, about 43 pigs will run one fridge.

Better than nothing, refrigeration would be super important in the Australian outback. But not so much to have a trash Las Vegas party town with giant lighted signs as Bartertown is shown in the movie.

They sum it up as follows.

> Some energy can be extracted from manure through anaerobic digestion. But this would likely comprise only a small fraction of the total energy needs of a typical farm. High investments in money and management along with difficulties in efficiently using methane make anaerobic digestion a questionable venture for most farmers.
>
> If energy and fertilizer shortages become more acute and pollution regulations concerning odor become more strict, methane generation may become a feasible process in waste management systems. Research is needed to reduce capital costs of methane generation systems and provide techniques for proper management of such systems.

The paper was written in 1993, and some of that has come true. They're writing from the POV of price-efficiency. In a post-apocalyptic scenario with no other sources of electricity, price is irrelevant. But the [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) of keeping the pigs is still important. It makes no sense to raise and feed pigs for power if you could be doing something better instead.

Of course, this assumes methane production is a by-product of raising pigs. The primary purpose of keeping the pigs is to eat the pigs. Otherwise it's an extremely wasteful process. Most of the food energy you feed the pigs will turn into more pig and making pigs go. If you don't eat the pigs, you're better off just burning the food you feed the pigs.

The other way to make this more efficient is to feed pigs food humans won't eat. That way you're extracting more calories, and making protein and power out of what would have been waste. Otherwise, if the pigs are eating the same food you are, you'd get more calories eating the pig feed.

In short, it only makes sense if you're keeping the pigs for eating, and if you're feeding them food waste. In that case you're getting more bang for your caloric buck.